# How do i make the textfield multiline in react native?

Tags: react-native, textfield, multiline

I have the textfield Name . When i write the name, it goes straight in one line. I want it go to next line after it reaches it reaches to the width of textfield. When i use `multiline = 'true'`, i got the error:

> Error while updating property 'multiline' of a view managed by:
>   Android TextInput.

Here is my code :

```
<TextField 
      label = {'Name :'}
      highlightColor = {'#00BCD4'} 
      style = {{height: 40}}
      multiline = 'true' />
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `multiline = 'true'` to `multiline = {true}`, the value of the property needs to be a boolean, not a string

```
<TextField 
      label = {'Name :'}
      highlightColor = {'#00BCD4'} 
      style = {{height: 40}}
      multiline = {true}
    />
```

Are you sure it's `TextField` and not `TextInput`?

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html

Comment: Yes, I am preety sure, it is TextField but not TextInput. When i do, multiline = {true}, i don't get error but the text is still go to the single line.

Comment: Well, which component is it? A 3rd party one?

Comment: Yeah, i add that. I think that library does not support multiline. Is there any better way, i use textfield and it supports multline too for android not ios?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `TextInput` rather than `TextField` and multiline should be a boolean rather than string like this...

```
<TextInput style={...} multiline={true} value={...} />
```

[Here's a demo](https://rnplay.org/apps/F75ppA)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple lines with the `TextField`, you have to use the `UITextField`